# Java XML Parsing - Parse XML with repeating Nodes

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

Folks, I am trying to parse the below XML structure:

```
<root>
  <data>
    <doc>
      <doc1></doc1>
      <doc2></doc2>
    </doc>
    <INFO>
        <INFO1></INFO1>
        <INFO2></INFO2>
        <INFO3></INFO3>
        <INFO4></INOF4>
    <ASSOC_SECTION>
      <ASSOC_SECTION1>hello1</ASSOC_SECTION1>
      <ASSOC_SECTION2></ASSOC_SECTION2>
    </ASSOC_SECTION>
    <ASSOC_SECTION>
     <ASSOC_SECTION1>hello2</ASSOC_SECTION1>
      <ASSOC_SECTION2></ASSOC_SECTION2>
    </ASSOC_SECTION>
   </INFO>
  </data>
 </root>
```

I am trying to read the values from the repeating node .
I am able to read the value of ASSOC_SECTION1 from the first repeating node, but while trying to read from the second node, I get a null pointer exception.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException, TransformerException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        File inputFile = new File(inputFile);
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = builder.parse(inputFile);
        document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
        System.out.println("Root Element-->"+document.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("ASSOC_SECTION");
        System.out.println(nodeList.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node data = nodeList.item(i);
            if(data.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE){
                Element element = (Element) data;
                System.out.println(element.getElementsByTagName("ASSOC_SECTION1").item(i).getTextContent());
            }
        }
```

Any idea as to why I am getting the null pointer issue here?

Comment: In `element.getElementsByTagName("ASSOC_SECTION1").item(i)` you're using the same index `i` for a completely different NodeSet... perhaps you meant `element.getElementsByTagName("ASSOC_SECTION1").item(0)` instead.

Comment: @potame Yeah that's what I need exactly. I tried printing it with the one that you suggested & it displays both the values. I want the values separately. Any idea as to how to get them separately?